# How can I record video clips on intervals automatically?

Tags: video-recording

Does anyone know of a way to record video clips of a set duration on a set interval? I am wanting to record a 1 minute video every 15 minutes automatically. I am using a Sony HDR-HC9 camcorder.

So far I have figured that I can connect the camcorder to my computer with a FireWire cable and get a live view. Then I hope I can program the computer to record the screen on my set duration and interval. The only downside with this is that I'll be losing the HD quality video from the camcorder for the resolution of the screen I'm recording on (13" laptop)...

Is there software to do this for me already?
Is there a way to capture the full quality of the camcorder's recording on my computer?

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to record the screen of a computer, wouldn't it make more sense to take a screen capture directly, rather than shooting a video of it?

Comment: Yes, I mean to do a screen capture if nobody else has a better idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I came up with to solve this problem:

```
cd \Users\Seibel\Documents\WinSendKeys

start WinSendKeys.exe
WinSendKeys -x "C:\Program Files\Sony\PlayMemories Home\TapeImporter\PMBTapeImporter.exe" -xd 10000 -w PMBTapeImporter.exe {TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}
set cmd="dir *.m2t /b/a-d | find /v /c "Users\Seibel\Desktop\Squid videos - Birk\Pcrit""
for /f %%i in (' %cmd% ') do set n_videos_pre=%%i
echo %n_videos_pre%
WinSendKeys -w PMBTapeImporter.exe {SPACE}
FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,1000) DO (

    timeout 60 /nobreak
    WinSendKeys -m "Import from Tape" #%%,100,10
    WinSendKeys -w PMBTapeImporter.exe {SPACE}
    timeout 1800 /nobreak
    WinSendKeys -m "Import from Tape" #%%,100,10

    WinSendKeys -w PMBTapeImporter.exe {SPACE}
)
```

It is a batch file that uses the default software for the Sony camcorder (PlayMemories Tape Importer) and a command line controlled button pressing program (WinSendKeys) to record my desired time at my desired intervals automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately if you want to keep HD quality then interval record at the camera. Hardware option is to use something like a Sony HVR-A1E that has this function built in. These are on eBay for 3-400 quid. Expensive solution!